# Access date time in milliseconds from nested soql query

Tags: soql, deserialize

This SOQL statement `SELECT name, (SELECT From__c, To__c FROM Trip__r) FROM Account limit 1` will return

`Smith [{"From__c":"2013-11-25T15:15:00.000+0000","To__c":"2013-11-27T15:15:00.000+0000"},{"From__c":"2013-11-27T20:58:00.000+0000","To__c":"2013-11-28T20:58:00.000+0000"}]`

I need to convert the time from Salesforce datetime onto the millisecond format. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked at the Apex Docs on Date/Time methods?

Answer (score 5):

The DateTime comes back ISO8601 formatted. So depending on your language of choice it should be fairly simple to parse them and then reformat as required.

E.g. .NET

```
DateTime.Parse("2013-11-27T20:58:00.000+0000");
```

E.g. Apex

```
DateTime d = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('2013-11-27T20:58:00.000+0000', DateTime.class);
```

Comment: I am having real trouble deserialising that field.

Comment: @Dzh Can you give me a specific example of the issue you are facing. Please include 1) What language you are using. 2) What you have tried and how it didn't work. 3) If applicable - what error you are getting. These would all be good points to add into your question.